# Using XML DSL route with camel-spring-boot: Misdeclaration of xmlns namespace

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

According to documentation http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html
, we can use XML DSL route with spring-boot.

When I use xquery as endpoint with syntax `<to uri="xquery:xquery/test.xq />`, then it works, but with syntax like below,

```
<transform>
    <xquery>resource:test.xq</xquery>
</transform>
```

or inline xquery transformation:

```
<transform>
    <xquery>concat('hello', 'world')</xquery>
</transform>
```

Then I get then the error:

> org.apache.camel.RuntimeExpressionException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Misdeclaration of xmlns namespace
>          at org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.evaluate(XQueryBuilder.java:155)
>   ~[camel-saxon-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          at org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.evaluate(XQueryBuilder.java:120)
>   ~[camel-saxon-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          at org.apache.camel.processor.TransformProcessor.process(TransformProcessor.java:50)
>   ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
>   ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>   [camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
>   [camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
>   [camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>   [camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:454)
>   [camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:223)
>   [camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:187)
>   [camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)
>   [camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)
>   [camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]
>          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]
>          at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]
>          at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Misdeclaration of xmlns
>   namespace
>          at net.sf.saxon.query.StaticQueryContext.declareNamespace(StaticQueryContext.java:719)
>   ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-12.jar:na]
>          at org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.initialize(XQueryBuilder.java:721)
>   ~[camel-saxon-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          at org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.evaluateAsString(XQueryBuilder.java:208)
>   ~[camel-saxon-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          at org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.evaluate(XQueryBuilder.java:130)
>   ~[camel-saxon-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
>          ... 19 common frames omitted

I tested the syntax with the sample project https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-spring, and it works, so maybe there is something wrong with camel-spring-boot component?

Answer (score 0):

A ticket was logged about this issue
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12994

And the issue/bug has now been fixed in Apache Camel.

As a workaround you need to either downgrade Camel/Saxon to a previous version that works. Or wait for the next release which has the fix. The JIRA ticket has fixed version numbers declared.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this. I will test it with camel 2.23.1 when it is availble.

Comment: Can you please shortly explain where these prefix value 'xmlns' or 'xml' are coming and used in `staticQueryContext.declareNamespace(prefix, uri);`, when we use syntax <transform> <xquery></xquery></transform>?